# try/catch within catch block is not executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, try-catch

I have written nested try/catch block like below.

```
static async myEx(){
  return 'hello';
}

static async myfunc() {

try{
  Logger.info('test1');
} catch(error){
  Logger.info('test2');
  try{
    Logger.info('test3');
    return await this.myEx();
  }catch(error2){
    Logger.info('test4');
  }
}
 return null;
}

myfunc();
```

when I run the code,I have got following as the output.

```
 test2
```

That means second try/catch block is not executed. I want to execute **myEX()** function within the second try block.  Can someone help me to resolve the issue?

Output that I want:

```
test2  
test3
hello
```

Comment: As written it won't go into the `catch` block at all; there's no way to diagnose a problem without knowing more about what you're actually doing and it what context.

Answer (score 0):

```js
async function myEx() {
    console.log('hello');
}

async function myfunc() {
    try {
        throw new Error();
        console.log('test1');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('test2');
        try {
            console.log('test3');
            return await myEx();
        } catch (error2) {
            console.log('test4');
        }
    }
    return null;
}

myfunc();
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.